# Strikethrough in a footnote latex

Tags: footnotes

I am revising a submitted manuscript, and the publishers would like removed text to be struck through and inserted text to be in bold. I am using `\sout{}` and `\textbf{}` to do strikethrough and boldface respectively. This works fine until I need to strike something out which appears in a footnote (using `\footnote{}`). When I try to do this I get several errors and the document does not compile.
For example,

```
\footnote{\sout{some example text}}
```

produces the following:
[image]

How can I use a strikethrough within a footnote?
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: It's impossible to provide help here without a minimum working example of the issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.